# EXC_BAD_ACCESS while trying to get reuseIdentifier of a cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, exc-bad-access

I am trying to get reuse identifier of a cell so i can set its height like this:

[image]

But getting an error:

[image]

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Change your algo so it won't crash.. it is bad to call cellForRowAtIndexPath to get the cell in heightForRowAtIndexPath call since it hasn't been drawn or initialized. .. You could either use the dynamic height generation ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath is called before cellForRowAtIndexPath, before a cell is displayed, the height needs to be calculated first.

you should get text from your data source, not from cell

Answer (score 0):

The `heightForRowAtIndexPath` is called before the cell is created. So you can't call `cellForRowAtIndexPath` in `heightForRowAtIndexPath`.